# How to make Firebase Dynamic Link open the exact post in the deeplink?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-dynamic-links

I have an application with three fragments each fragment includes different posts.
I've created dynamic link which is sent when the user share the post, and it has the postID,

Dynamic link:

```
    "https://s5xta.app.goo.gl/?link=http://mywebsite.com/" + postID() + "&apn=com.myapp.firebase.quickstart.database"
```

Which generate the deeplink, for example:
https://s5xta.app.goo.gl/?link=http://mywebsite.com/-L3LLFhi94w-d_zWVDwu&apn=com.myapp.firebase.quickstart.database

Where: **L3LLFhi94w-d_zWVDwu** is the postID.

And I have the below code in the MainActivity to handle the link.

```
            FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                 //Retrive DynamicLink
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                    }

                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    Uri data = intent.getData();



                    // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                    // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                    // account.
                    // ...

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    // Display deep link in the UI
                    if (deepLink != null) {
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                                "Found deep link!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_view_receive))
                          //      .setText(deepLink.toString());
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "getDynamicLink: no link found");
                    }
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                }
            });
    // [END get_deep_link]
```

When the user clicks the link, it's open the installed application, but it goes to the last post on the top of the first fragment.

What should I do, in order to take the user to the correct post based on the postID that stated in the deeplink?